# Can anybody help me out with my Darkmode?

Tags: javascript

I want do have a basic Darkmode linked to a key press. I'am a Beginner in JavaScript and i cannot get it to work. I want it like, you press a key, the Darkmode turns on with a Cookie over js-cookie, and I press the same Key again to turn off the Darkmode and delete the cookie. Can anybody help me?

There is my Code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("folie");

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);
function checkKeyPress(key) {
let zahl = 1;
 if (key.keyCode == "70") {
    if (zahl == 1) {
      zahl++
      dark()
      Cookies.set("Darkmode", "An");
    }

  if (zahl == 2) {
    zahl--
    Cookies.remove("Darkmode")
  }

 }
 }

var DarkCookie = Cookies.get("Darkmode");
if (DarkCookie == 'An') {
  dark();
}

 function dark() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
 }
```

**Edit:**

Ok i've got it:

```
let CookieDarkMode = false;

function toggleDarkMode() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);

function checkKeyPress(key) {
  if (key.keyCode === 70) { //"F" has been pressed
    CookieDarkMode = !CookieDarkMode;
    console.log("Cookie Dark mode: " + CookieDarkMode);
    toggleDarkMode();
    if (CookieDarkMode) {
      Cookies.set("Darkmode", "An");
    }else {
        Cookies.remove("Darkmode");
    }
  }
};
var DarkCookie = Cookies.get("Darkmode")
if (DarkCookie == 'An') {
  CookieDarkMode = true;
  toggleDarkMode();
}
```

Comment: You need more design about it. What you need is some tools : "Is dark mode enabled ?" "If not, what is the default" "Change saved state" "Initialize using current state" "Listen & apply changes"
I hope, it will help you to design your needs.

Comment: You're setting `zahl` to 1 then turning on darkmode, adding 1 to `zahl`, then `zahl` is 2 and you're turning darkmode off. All in the same single call to `checkKeyPress()`. Simple fix is to increment `zahl` after the is it 2 check, but this isn't a robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to store a number. You can just get the previous cookie value with a boolean

```js
let CookieDarkMode = false;

function toggleDarkMode() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);

function checkKeyPress(key) {
  if (key.keyCode === 70) { //"F" has been pressed
    CookieDarkMode = !CookieDarkMode;
    console.log("Cookie Dark mode: " + CookieDarkMode);
    toggleDarkMode();
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</body>
```

Comment: yes i know but if you reload the site the Darkomde is off again

Answer (score 0):

your problem is on your `checkKeyPress` function, you always check for the `zahl` value, but it will always start as `1`.

for demostration purposes you are doing this basically:

```js
function sum(){
  let zahl = 1;
  zahl++
  console.log(zahl)
}

// you will never see a 3, because you are creating `zhl` 
// in each call with a value of 1
sum();
sum();
sum();
sum();
```

therefore, each time you check for the `zahl` variable, it will be `1` and will always  enter the `if` that turns on the `darkmode`.

the solution for your code would be to move the `zahl` variable outside the function scope:

```
let zahl = 1; // outside the function scope
var elem = document.getElementById("folie");

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);

function checkKeyPress(key) {

  if (key.keyCode == "70") {
    if (zahl == 1) {
      zahl++
      dark()
      Cookies.set("Darkmode", "An");
    }else if (zahl == 2) {
      zahl--
      Cookies.remove("Darkmode")
      dark(); //you should call dark here as well to toggle to the other mode.
    }

  }
}

var DarkCookie = Cookies.get("Darkmode");
if (DarkCookie == 'An') {
  dark();
}

function dark() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

note: it doesn't look like the best implementation, it would be easier to read if you use a boolean for the state of the mode or if you want multiple types, you can use the name as a key for each of the modes.

Comment: He also has a logic issue, which your answer no longer has :)

Comment: yes @JDunken I noticed. I changed to have an `if/else` instead of double `if`